# Wondering if my shared member is working?

Tags: c++

I have a shared_ptr I'm trying to use in two functions of a class, not sure if I have it working right. The shared object class I'm using might be broken, but it's not my repo so I'm wanting to check if it's my issue on my end.

**myHeader.h**

```
#include "otherClass.h"

namespace myheader {
class myClass : {
public: 
  // Constructor
  myClass();
  ~myClass() = default;

  bool incomingMessage();

private: 
  std::shared_ptr<randomnamespace::OtherClass> otherClass_ = std::make_shared<randomnamespace::OtherClass>();
};
};
```

**myClass.cpp**

```
#include "myHeader.h"

using namespace myheader;

myClass::myClass() 
  :
  otherClass_()

{
  otherClass_->setConfiguration(x);
  std::cout << "Debug: Initialized";
}

bool myClass::incomingMessage() {
  otherClass_->sendData();
  std::cout << "Debug: Data sent";
  return true;
}
```

I'm wondering if it seems to be shared correctly?

I've tried running this(compiling works), and the otherClass_->() calls don't work in either place. Have tried testing both individually with the other commented out, and I don't get the Debug print's after the otherClass_-> calls.

Comment: What do you mean by "shared correctly"? Shared with whom? You have a private member that instantiates a new object on creation, I don't see any kind of sharing going on

Comment: get rid of `otherClass_()`. This initialises `_otherClass` to an empty shared ptr. You do not want that.

Comment: You are initializing your member from the constructor, although you already have initialized it directly.. Remove `: otherClass_()`. Other than that, I don't see that you retuirn the shared_ptr anywhere. It looks like you can use a unique_ptr.

Comment: @ThomasWeller would removing the otherClass_() still have the otherClass_->() call's sharing the pointer across the separate function? My coworkers mentioned otherClass_ being missing from the initializer list(in prior code), would that still be a case? Or maybe they didn't see it initialized as a private in the header?

Comment: @Jacob, please don't edit the question and make the code worse. You have now introduced `x` which is not declared and nobody knows the type. What we need here is a [mre]. Something that we can copy/paste into our IDEs and see what's wrong. Adding `x` only makes it worse.

Answer (score 1):

You try to initialize `otherClass_` twice:

- once with a default member initializer:

  ```
    std::shared_ptr<randomnamespace::OtherClass> otherClass_ = std::make_shared<randomnamespace::OtherClass>();
  ```
- once with a *mem-initializer* in the constructor:

  ```
    myClass::myClass(): otherClass_()
  ```

The standard says that when this happens, the default member initializer is ignored and the member is initialized according to the mem-initializer in ctor. Here that means that you initialize `otherclass_` to be an empty shared pointer...

You should remove the offending initialization in ctor:

```
myClass::myClass() 
{
  otherClass_->init();
  std::cout << "Debug: Initialized";
}
```

Comment: The ->init() call(changed it to  `otherClass_->setConfiguration(x);` for better understanding) is actually a call with a parameter to setup otherClass_ to be shared, for use with `otherClass_->sendData();`

Answer (score 1):

#### Main question

```cpp
myClass::myClass() 
  :
  otherClass_()
```

This initializes your member (`otherClass_`) with nothing from the constructor.

This will override the definition of

```cpp
 std::shared_ptr<randomnamespace::OtherClass> otherClass_ = std::make_shared<randomnamespace::OtherClass>();
```

where you already have initialized it before correctly.

Solution:

1. Remove `: otherClass_()` from the constructor.
2. Remove the initialization from `otherClass_` and use `:otherClass_(std::make_shared<randomnamespace::OtherClass>())` to initialize it from the constructor.

#### Other notes

Remove the colon after `class myClass : {`.

To implement `incomingMessage()` you need

```cpp
bool myClass::incomingMessage() {
```

Other than that, I don't see that you return `otherClass_` anywhere or pass it as a parameter. You don't share it, you only use it. It looks like you can use a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: So the init() call was just me putting a bad filler in, a better example of what I'm doing there is `otherClass_->setConfiguration(x);` And I'm wanting to use `otherClass_->sendData();` based on how otherClass_ uses the setConfiguration().

You mention using `:otherClass_(std::make_shared<randomnamespace::OtherClass>())` is that putting it in `myClass::myClass(:otherClass_(std::make_shared<randomnamespace::OtherClass>())) ` of myClass.cpp, sorta confused on this part.

Comment: I'm doing 
```
myClass::myClass() : otherClass_(std::make_shared<randomnamespace::OtherClass>())
```
In my header should my private declaration be changed/moved of `otherClass_`, removing it there though causes me errors.

Comment: With me making changes regarding my previous comments, I have `otherClass_->setConfiguration();` working. `otherClass_->sendData();` seems to freeze up, even with adding the `myClass::` to the bool function.

Comment: @Jacob: you really seem to be confused. I don't really understand your question. Maybe you want to start with a hello world example on initialization and constructors? I don't think it's a good idea to implement your suggestion in the header. Leave it in the cpp file.

Comment: @Jacob: I don't know how `sendData()` is implemented. Maybe it sends data synchronously, in which case it's normal that the application stalls until the data was processed. You would then need multithreading to avoid a blocked UI.

Comment: Tried with removing the private initializer in myHeader.h, and get `class myclass:MyClass does not have any field named 'otherClass_'`.

Comment: @Jacob: do you have someone near you to help you at your desk? You're trying too many things without knowing what you do. It seems you need some guidance as you go. You do *programming by coincidence* or *cargo cult programming*. You won't get far with that approach. Learn C++ before you write C++ in real world projects.

Comment: @Jacob See [How to overcome programming by coincidence?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/202025/109304)